# Casting from Timestamp/String to Date

Tags: javascript, mysql, pentaho, kettle

I need to insert to database two variables:
- "start" with value "9:00"
- "end" with value "20:00"

It can be types String or Timestamp, i would prefer the string. But in database table the fields are "Time" type. So how to cast it? I got only time values without full date like month, days and years.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read, if you want to insert a string into a MySQL `TIME` column, it will have to have the format `HH:mm:ss`.  So the easiest solution for you might be to obtain your start and end times in the format of `09:00:00` and `20:00:00`.

I expect the following `INSERT` statement to proceed without error:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (`time_from`, `time_to`)
VALUES
    ('09:00:00', '20:00:00')
```

To be clear, I would recommend putting in a little effort in your code to obtain time data in this format.  Then just insert it into MySQL without further hassle.

Comment: I have noticed that its Time type not Date.

Comment: Yes, but it is provided by customer ;) So he puts times like this "8:30", 1:30 etc.

Comment: @Touche Can you try running this query: `SELECT TIME_FORMAT('9:00', '%H:%i') FROM yourTable` ... does it work?

Comment: Yes its work. I added with Javascript ":00" postifx but i got error:

"Couldn't convert string [7:15:00] to a date using format [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS] on offset location 1
2016/12/05 09:50:41 - INSERT/UPDATE my_table.0 - 7:15:00"

Comment: You're using the wrong function.  Do one of the following: Either `INSERT` `'07:15:00'` directly into the column, _or_ use `TIME_FORMAT('07:15:00', '%H:%i:%s')`.

Comment: Ok. I did it. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: @Touche Maybe update somewhere telling us what you actually did.

Answer (score 0):

In a Date Field you van only Store Dates without time Information.
So you Must change the fieldtype or add a nee Field for this

Comment: I have noticed that its Time type not Date. I addded image to main post.